# Js/Canvas last rect of a real time updated line needs to be bigger than the line itself

Tags: javascript, canvas

The way I'm drawing my line right now is point/rect by point/rect.

It gets automatically updated.

I want a line that has the last recy at time T bigger than the rest of the line. At time T+1 I want the same thing, only because I draw my line with previous points/rect this is very tricky.

The reason I want this is if my line makes a circle, and the trajectory keeps repeating as the same circle, I want to know where my current point is at, therefore making it bigger will show me where I am on the screen.

I don't know how I can do this.

Here is the current code:

```
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = red_colour;
context.rect(posX,posY,1,1);
context.lineWidth = "1";
context.fill();
```

This is in an infinite loop where posx and posy get updated.

Comment: What do you mean by `It gets automatically updated.` ... any `rect(posX,posY,1,1)` is just a dot not a line ...
Can you add a bit more code, a minimal working example will be nice: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It is just a dot. But then comes another dot, and another etc. Imagine it just being a straight line if you want. Point is, this line is constructed with these successive dots.
And there lies the root of my problem. 
How do I make the last dot bigger than all the previous ones, because the last one then becomes the one before the last in the next step.

Comment: Sorry I can not really picture what you mean can you add some working code and maybe a few pictures of what you would like to see on your output